# Haskell - combine foldr and replicate?

Tags: haskell, fold

Now I know in general how to use foldr, I usually write with a recursive function in mind, eg for me when I see:

```
   sum xs = foldr (+) 0 xs
```

What I think is:

```
   sum [] = 0
   sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

Which as far as I know is basically what foldr means.

Now, I have this code:

```
   printLine :: [Int] -> String
   printLine [] = "+"
   printLine (x:xs) = '+' : replicate x '-' ++ printLine xs
```

What it does, is it takes for example  [5,4] and then it prints "+-----+----+". Now, I really want to know how to write this using foldr. It follows the general idea of the recursive function so I think it should be doable. I've tried with lambda function and flip replicate shenanigans but nothing seems to work. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
withFoldr :: [Int] -> String
withFoldr xs = foldr go "+" xs
  where go x b = ('+' : replicate x '-') ++ b
```

In general, when you have an expression

```
f as = foldr go a bs
```

then `a` equals `f []`. The `go` function has signature `go :: a -> b -> b`
and corresponds to the recursive case of `printLine`:

```
-- match up with go :: a -> b -> b
printLine (x:xs) = '+' : replicate x '-' ++ printLine xs
```

Here we identify `a` with `x` and `b` with `printLine xs`, so `go` becomes:

```
go a b = ('+' : replicate a '-') ++ b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't consider where :)

Comment: @Thomas: Note that `go` in the where block is just defined to be a (non-recursive) function, so you can use a lambda: `printLine = foldr (\x b -> ('+' : replicate x '-') ++ b) "+"`.  It's not necessarily clearer or less clear, but just wanted to make the point that you *could* still do it with a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
ghci> let printLine ns = foldr (++) "+" $ map (\n -> '+' : replicate n '-') ns
ghci> printLine [5,2,33]
"+-----+--+---------------------------------+"
```

Comment: Oh that's really clever! I love it!

Answer (score 2):

You can write a version of it with very little change:

```
printL = foldr alg "+" where
  alg x xs = '+' : replicate x '-' ++ xs
```

It might help to think of `xs` as the component that has already been handled appropriately; you handle `x` (by prepending `'+'` to `-` replicated `x` times), and then append the 'already-handled' `xs` to that.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you want a point free representation to pass to `foldr` as an academic exercise. Here is how I would approach the problem.

First, I would write the expression using lambdas:

```
Prelude> let pp = foldr (\x -> \s -> s ++ (replicate x '-') ++ "+") "+"
Prelude> pp [4,5]
"+-----+----+"
```

Now, I would work towards making the expression point free one argument at a time. First, eliminating `s`:

```
Prelude> let pp = foldr (\x -> flip (++) ((replicate x '-') ++ "+")) "+"
Prelude> pp [4,5]
"+-----+----+"
```

And now, `x`, first by moving it as the last argument of the internal function:

```
Prelude> let pp = foldr (\x -> flip (++) ((flip replicate '-' x) ++ "+")) "+"
Prelude> pp [4,5]
"+-----+-
```

Then yet another step:

```
Prelude> let pp = foldr (\x -> flip (++) (flip (++) "+" (flip replicate '-' x))) "+"
Prelude> pp [4,5]
"+-----+----+"
```

Now this is getting slightly out of hand so this is a shorthand to see the next step:

```
Prelude> let f = flip (++)
Prelude> let g = f "+"
Prelude> let h = flip replicate '-'
Prelude> let pp = foldr (\x -> f (g (h x))) "+"
```

Making the last point-free is easy!

```
Prelude> let pp = foldr (f . g . h) "+"
Prelude> pp [4,5]
"+-----+----+"
```

Now replacing the `f`, `g` and `h`, you'll get your answer. However, this should merely be an academic exercise and I wouldn't imagine using something like this in real production code.

---

@WillNess suggested using [operator sections (see right section)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator), which I had completely forgotten about. They allow one to omit the flip at two places, resulting in something more eyesome:

Original:

```
Prelude> let pp = foldr ((flip (++)) . (flip (++) "+") . (flip replicate '-')) "+"
```

Changes to:

```
Prelude> let pp = foldr ((flip (++)) . (++ "+") . (`replicate` '-')) "+"
Prelude> pp [4,5]
"+-----+----+"
```

Comment: I thought there'd be a way with flip! That's quite interesting, thanks :)

Comment: @Thomas But I reiterate, this should only be an academic exercise, and not something I would want to find in real code. The other solutions provide how to solve the problem in a more canonical way.

Comment: Oh that's quite alright, it's in fact an academic exercise :p

Comment: `flip`s might be easier on the eyes with operator sections: ``foldr (flip (++) . (++ "+") . (`replicate` '-')) "+"``. but why in reverse?

Comment: @Thomas Updated the answer with a more visually pleasing solution.